# Why this variable is null?

Tags: android, kotlin

I working on wallpaper application. When i click the image, activiy is changing and image's id saving memory. In second activity id is true but findViewById(id) always null. By the way when i move the setWallpaper function to MainActivity.kt code works properly.

MainActivity.kt

```
fun clickImage(v: View) {
       val intent = Intent(this, SecActivity::class.java)
       intent.putExtra("id", v.id)
       startActivity(intent)
}
```

SecActivity.kt

```
class SecActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sec)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
        button.setOnClickListener{
            setWallpaper()
        }
    }

    fun setWallpaper() {
        var id = intent.getIntExtra("id",0)
        var img  = findViewById<ImageView>(id)
        val bitmap: Bitmap = (img.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable).getBitmap()
        val wallpaperManager: WallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/a001"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="clickImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a001"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/a002"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="clickImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a002"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/a003"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="clickImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a003"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/a004"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="clickImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a004"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="clickImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a005"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="clickImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a006"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

activity_sec.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".SecActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/wall"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:src="@drawable/a004"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/btn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEKCy.jpg

Comment: Can you show your xml so we can check if you have attached any image to it or not.

Comment: Because the 2nd activity layout hasn't that id.

Comment: You must make sure that there is a button with the id `btn` in the layout of your second activity.

Comment: @Ashish added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ImageView` belong to `MainActivity`. You can not find view from other activity (in this case `SecActivity`).

Comment: Pass your image resource id, not your `ImageView` id.
`val intent = Intent(this, SecActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("id", R.drawable.EXAMPLE_IMAGE)
startActivity(intent)`

Comment: And in `SecActivity` create bitmap like this.
`val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, id)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the `id` used in the 1st Activity (and 1st layout) and you are trying to get a view **with same id** in a 2nd Activity with a different layout with:

```
var img  = findViewById<ImageView>(id)
```

you **will not** find that view simply because the 2nd activity layout **hasn't** that id.

Comment: So, how can i do that?

Comment: Since you want just display a bitmap, pass something you can use to get the selected image (an url, a name, a resource name, a key on db... it depends by your project, but not the layout id).

Answer (score 0):

You should get the selected image Uri and pass it to second activity and use this Image Uri to show and set the image as wallpaper.
Basically pass Uri as string to second activity instead of I'd of image view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take off findViewById. You can reference btn id directly

something like this:

```
  ...
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sec)
    btn.setOnClickListener{
        setWallpaper()
    }
  }
   ...
```